# Can i use the same Fragments more than one place?

Tags: java, android

I create a lot of the same fragments. They have the same shape. Can I delete all of them and use just one in more than place if I relied on position like this?

```java
 ViewPager pager = getView().findViewById( R.id.pager_saraya );

        for(int i=0 ; i<data.size() ; i++)
        {
            if(data.get( i ).getImage() == R.drawable.food_1)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> det=new ArrayList<>(  );

                for( int j=1 ;j<=7;j++)
                {

                    int photoId= getResources().getIdentifier( "makdoos_"+i,"drawable" ,getContext().getPackageName() );

                    det.add(photoId);
                }

                det.add( R.drawable.seha );
                ImageAdapter_details adapter_makdoos = new ImageAdapter_details( getContext(), det );
                pager.setAdapter( adapter_makdoos );
            }

            else if(data.get( i ).getImage() == R.drawable.food_2)
            {

                ArrayList<Integer> det=new ArrayList<>(  );

                for( int j=1 ;j<=10;j++)
                {

                    int photoId= getResources().getIdentifier( "fish"+i,"drawable" ,getContext().getPackageName() );

                    det.add(photoId);
                }

                det.add( R.drawable.seha );
                ImageAdapter_details adapter_makdoos = new ImageAdapter_details( getContext(), det );
                pager.setAdapter( adapter_makdoos );
            }
        }
```

Comment: That was the entire purpose of Fragments to reuse views without having to repeat code.

Comment: i use fragment contain viewpager.. i want to use the same viewpager with another photos in more than place.. can i explain what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question if you can move common code to one place and use it where it is needed is Yes you can do it and is a good idea. 
Follow the principle of DRY

- D Do not
- R repeat
- Y yourself

You can move the common code to a helper or a util class name it that fits your standards. Make it static or non static and it is ready to be used.

Comment: thanks.. I do it already.. i create many objects from the same fragment. but i have another question in the next  comment.. please follow it

Comment: when i send ArrayList<Object> via method from another fragments which contain data.. i had a problem:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: It could be due to two reasons 1. The list you are sending is null. 2) The object added in the list is null. Add check for not null on the object before invoking any methods of the list or data object taken from the list